# Is Firebase 3 node.js server authentication going to change?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

Right now seems like the only way to authenticate a node.js server is by passing the a service account private key which means the private key lays in RAM which is something that clearly won't pass a security review.

Is this method going to change sometimes soon to something like passing a token with expiration which can be generated in a secured manner somewhere else?
I'm talking about something like Firebase 2 authentication (but not HS256 with a shared secret)
would love to get a comment from Firebase's engineers team.
Thanks

Comment: We just made some change to the authentication in the node.js SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.3.0.

Comment: well , this is actually cool.
didn't see a reference for this in documentation.
Thanks for the response @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if the regular documentation was updated. I'll ask around and file a note if it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to answer that.

you can do something like this :

```
  var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

and then doing

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(<TOKEN>)
```

before calling

```
firebase.database().ref()
```

you can get your config by going to your firebase's app overview (`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<APP_NAME>/overview`) and pressing "Add firebase to your web app"